# Adjust to size text DF to image Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, image

I have the following code, this code converts a df into a sand plotly image, at the moment it generates the image but I need the width of the columns of the df to fit the text contained, how can I do it? I am new using Python

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import pandas as pd

docFilename = 'Plantilla.xlsx'
docFilepath = 'C:/Users/user/Documents/Pruebas Pytonn/' + docFilename
##
htmlFilename = 'image1.png'
htmlFilepath = 'C:/Users/user/Documents/Pruebas Pytonn/' + htmlFilename

# Create a data frame
si_units = {
    'TARJETAS': ['4732XXXXXXX74621',],
    'CEDULA': ['1234567890'],
    'NOMBRES TARJETA HABIENTE': ['Juan Perez'],
    'CUPO ASIGNADO': ['500'],
    'CUPO MODIFICADO': ['550'],
    'Temporal / Deifinitiva': ['Temporal'],
    'Periodo de modificacion': ['18 al 30 de septiembre']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(si_units)

fig =  ff.create_table(df)
#fig.update_traces(textposition='inside')
fig.update_layout(
    autosize=True,
    font={'size':8},
    #width=500,
    #height=200,
    uniformtext_minsize=8,
    uniformtext_mode='hide',
    textposition='inside'
)

fig.write_image(htmlFilepath, scale=0)
```